# C# Impossible to Run Command with Spaces in the EXE

Tags: c#, process, command

I am trying to execute this command via C# from Visual Studio 2017 target framework is .NET 4.5. No matter what I tried wrapping it in quotes it doesn't fire due to there being a space in the `EXE` file's name. I read everyone else fixed this issue by wrapping them in quotes well it's not working. I am on Windows 10.0.19045.4046

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Export Current Settings
    string cncmd = GetCnCMD();
    string AMD3D = (System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\AMD3DSettings.zip").Replace(@"\\", @"\");

    Run("\"" + cncmd + "\" export \"" + AMD3D + "\" >%TMP%\\Log3d.txt");
}

static void Run(string command)
{
    Console.WriteLine(command);

    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/k " + command;

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}

public static string GetCnCMD()
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey HKLM = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        RegistryKey cnkey = HKLM.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\AMD\CN");

        string dir = (string) cnkey.GetValue("InstallDir");

        if (dir.EndsWith(@"\") || dir.EndsWith(@"/"))
        {
            dir = dir.Substring(0, dir.Length - 1);
        }

        return dir + @"\cncmd.exe";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + e.GetType());
        string HOMEDRIVE = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System).Substring(0, 1);
        string cncmd = HOMEDRIVE + @":\Program Files\AMD\CNext\CNext\cncmd.exe";

        if (File.Exists(cncmd))
            return cncmd;

        cncmd = HOMEDRIVE + @":\Program Files (x86)\AMD\CNext\CNext\cncmd.exe";

        if (File.Exists(cncmd))
            return cncmd;

        // Check older or newer likely paths
        cncmd = HOMEDRIVE + @":\Program Files\AMD\CNext\cncmd.exe";

        if (File.Exists(cncmd))
            return cncmd;

        cncmd = HOMEDRIVE + @":\Program Files (x86)\AMD\CNext\cncmd.exe";

        if (File.Exists(cncmd))
            return cncmd;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Output cmd window 1:

```
"C:\Program Files\AMD\CNext\CNext\cncmd.exe" export "C:\Users\jredfox\AppData\Local\Temp\AMD3DSettings.zip" >%TMP%\Log3d.txt
```

Output cmd window 2:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Why are you running "cmd.exe" rather than "cncmd.exe" directly?

Comment: This is like someone asking how to fix a SQL  query in C# code that they've never run in their database directly. Open a console window and run your command there. Once it works as expected, that's the commandline you need to run in your app.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. You should learn how to use string interpolation and also the `Path.Combine` method. That will make it much more succinct and readable.

Comment: @gunr2171 calling it directly won't separate the arguments you have to use cmd.exe in order to do that according to other questions on here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney has nothing to do with SQL query I am calling proprietary AMD's CNCMD.exe which allows for exporting current graphics and even display settings. This is so you can see in a JSON file the current settings and edit them

Comment: "calling it directly won't separate the arguments" that doesn't make sense to me. I see that you're doing a `>` STDOUT redirect to print to a file, but you can easily do that with C# directly.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with a SQL query. Good grief. I said that this question is LIKE when someone asks how to fix a SQL query in their application code without ever having tested that query in their database. You know what "like" means, right? "Similar to". You're doing a similar thing. You are asking how to fix a commandline in your application code, apparently without ever having bothered to test at a command prompt. Open a console window and test there. Only when you have it working there should you try to transfer it to your applicatiom code.

Comment: @gunr2171 I basically agree with the idea of directly calling "cncmd.exe", but in reality, redirecting output in C# is not easy. You need to know how to expand %TMP%, configure UseShellExecute and RedirectStandardOutput and then use ReadToEnd and WriteAllText to write the output to a file. You also need to know that you'd better call ReadToEnd before WaitForExit to avoid deadlock. Sometime you may encounter a large amount of output or the executing file refuses redirection issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startInfo.Arguments = $@"/k ""{command}""";
```

Just wrap your command string in another pair of quotation marks if the command string contains multiple quotation mark pairs, because cmd will strip the outmost quotation marks. See the document to know the rules of the `/k` switch: [cmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd#remarks)

Addtional notes:

1. I suggest you to add the `/s` switch, so regardless of whether the command string complies with those rules, the above method is always applicable.
2. Using the `/k` switch will require you to manually exit the cmd process. If this is not what you expected, you should replace it with the `/c` switch.

   ```
   startInfo.Arguments = $@"/s /c ""{command}""";
   ```

Comment: yes wrapping the command in another pair of quotes seems to fix it but there is no explanation as to why as everywhere else online it wasn't required. I also don't understand your syntax. I just did command = "\"" + command + "\"";

Comment: can you explain what the /s flag does to cmd? I added the /s flag and the command no longer works with or without the extra quotes

Comment: @OW2IsTrash: That syntax is called "interpolated strings". Read up on it, it makes your code much more readable, especially in the case of quotation marks.

Comment: @OW2IsTrash Have you seen that link? You can also get an explanation by running `cmd /?`. The `/s` flag tells cmd to always strip the quotes around the command and leave the rest of the command unchanged.